# Recommendations for UX/UI Bootcamper / newbie coder

Tags: pc, apple

What PC (laptop or desktop) would be good for a relatively newbie coder who'll be entering a UX/UI boot camp soon?

A little background: I'm a lifelong PC/windows users (I'm coming from the business world), and while I've purchased and tried a few Apple/Mac products in my life, they've never quite gelled with me. I tend to dislike the fact that they're SO proprietary, i.e., I resent spending money on special chargers and cables, and I dislike the garbage bin (sorry, I'm nitpicking).

I'm located in the US (New Mexico), so I'll probably be ordering something though we do have a Best Buy here in town, currently closed due to COVID restrictions.

Budget is somewhat open though I'd prefer to be under $2K if possible.

In any case, should I view this opportunity as my foray into the Mac world, or should I stick with PC-based tech since that's what I'm most familiar and comfortable with?

Thanks for sharing your tips and thoughts, particularly if you've been in a similar position.

Comment: Please go to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and read the Quality Guidelines section, then revise your question to make it more specific, especially with regard to your location and budget. https://ux.stackexchange.com may also have discussed this, so a search there might be worthwhile. That being said, stick with what you know; in the boot camps I've survived, Windows and Linux boxen abounded, so there's no need to Buy Different. I would recommend a laptop if you will attend that boot camp in person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenovo's [ThinkPad P73](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p/ThinkPad-P73/p/20QRS00100) (model part number [20QRS00100](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_P73?M=20QRS00100)) is an excellent machine for [just under two kilobucks today when ordered from Lenovo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io9Ca.png), with a 17.3" screen, Core i9-9750H CPU, 16 GB of (expandible) DDR4 RAM, a NVIDIA Quadro T2000 GPU, and a 512 GB SSD. It's fast and upgradable, the screen's large, and it's very easy to service when you need to beef it up. Lenovo's documentation is first rate, and IBM Global Service will stand behind you.

I'd recommend Lenovo ThinkPads over other machines with the same specs because of the last two items, even if I had to pay more.